# How to Calculate maximum distance between transmitter and receiver in wireless communication

Tags: wireless, communication, antenna, gain, signal-to-noise

how to calculate maximum distance between transmitter and receiver in free space radio communication by having transmitted power, antenna gain and noise-to-signal ratio ?

Comment: Here at EE.SE we don't assist with questions that are quite obviously homework problems unless there is considerable effort shown first.  Even then, some are hesitant to help.

Comment: It is not a HW question. It is an exam question. I don't need someone solve it, explaining the question, and how to approach it would be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Find an expression for S (received signal) in function of distance d. (Friis equation).

2) Calculate N (noise) = FkBT. You might assume T=290 K

3) Solve d in equation SNR=25 dB

Comment: Is it three different approached? If it is then I go with the first (Friis equation). But how to consider attenuation in Friis equation? Show I substract it from the antenna gain?

In friis equation we should have both receiving and transmitting power, we have only the transmitting power, how to calculate receiving power?

Comment: No, those are the three steps involved :-). The receiving power is S, you will solve for it in step 3. At step 1 you only need to express S in function of distance d.

Comment: I think I got it, I will try to solve it and will return back to you. Thanks!

Comment: The question said `The receiver has a noise factor if 11 dB`, can we assume SNR(dB) is 11?

Comment: No, the noise figure appears in step 2). It is letter F. Of course in equation N=FkTB values are not in dB. You can use instead N|dBW=F|dB + 10 log (kTB)

Comment: Actually the formula you mentioned haven't covered in the course literature, here is a list of formula that can be used to solve the problem ![Formulas](http://i.imgur.com/vOfzQj0.png)

Comment: Indeed this formula is not in your list :-). But you really need it to solve the problem. Actually, noise factor doesn't appear in any of your formulas neither!